# Storing a score in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I have made a short game in which you have to guess the area of the shape in question. Only the triangle works so far and the correct answer is B for testing.

I am trying to store the user's progress by putting it into a text file, but when I call a function to update the score, it overwrites the file so the score is removed! How can I get around this, and if I can't is there another way of doing this, because I want the user to be able to go from level to level?

My code:

```
User_Points = '0'

def LoginScreen():
    print("Welcome to Area Trainer")
    print("Please enter the username for your account")
    global user_name
    user_name = str(input())
    save = open(user_name + '.txt', 'w')
    save.write(str(User_Points))


    PasswordCheck= True
    while PasswordCheck:
        user_password = input("Type in your password: ")
        if len(user_password) < 8:
            print("Your password must be 8 characters long")
        elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in user_password):
            print("You need a number in your password")
        elif not any(i.isupper() for i in user_password):
            print("You need a capital letter in your password")
        elif not any(i.islower() for i in user_password):
            print("You need a lowercase letter in your password")
        else:
            PasswordCheck = False


def MenuTriangle():
    global User_Points
    User_Points = ''
    print('''Here is a triangle with a height of 12 cm and a width of 29 cm
    /\     |                *Not to scale.
   /  \    |
  /    \   | 12 cm
 /      \  |
 <------->
    29 cm
    You must find out the area and select the correct answer from these options''')
    print('''A) 175
        B) 174
        C) 2000
        D) 199

           ''')
    user_input = input().upper()

    if user_input == "A":
            print("I'm sorry this is incorrect, but you still have a chance to get 1 point!")
            MenuTriangle2()

    elif user_input == "C":
            print("I'm sorry this is incorrect, but you still have a chance to get 1 point!")
            MenuTriangle2()

    elif user_input == "D":
            print("I'm sorry this is incorrect, but you still have a chance to get 1 point!")
            MenuTriangle2()

    elif user_input == "B":
            print("Congratulations! You got it right; someone's a smart cookie. Here have two points!")
            reading = open(user_name + '.txt')
            score = reading.read()
            score = score + '2'
            print("Your score is", score)
            save = open(user_name + '.txt', 'a')
            save.write(str(score))
            MenuStart()

def MenuStart():

    print("Welcome to the mathematical area game!")
    print("In this game you will be required to calculate the area of multiple shapes.")
    print("To do this you must know how to calculate the area of different shapes with increasing difficulty.")
    print('''Please select a shape you want to play,
    A) Triangle
    B) Square
    C) Circle''')
    user_input = input().upper()

    if user_input == "A":
        print("You have chosen to calculate the area of a triangle!")
        MenuTriangle()

    elif user_input == "B":
        print("You have chosen to calculate the area of a square!")
        MenuSquare()

    elif user_input == "C":
        print("You have chosen the calculate the area of a circle!")
        MenuCircle()

    else:
        print("Oops! I didn't understand that >:")
        MenuStart()


LoginScreen()
MenuStart()
```

Comment: Why did you post your entire game? We only need to see the part where the score is written to the file. Please post a **Minimal** but complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue you're experiencing is?  You seem to be opening, reading, and appending to the file properly.  By the way, you may find the `with` statement helpful for opening files - http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm.

Comment: why don't you check if the answer is correct (`B`) else your print and function call, this would shorten your code a bit

Comment: Hi, I'm not a very experienced user of python so I'm probably missing some bits here and there and I apologise for that but when the user answers a question I wanted the users score to be stored in the file but because I'm calling the function again it is just being over written so the file is just blank and has nothing in it, so obviously my score isnt being stored correctly... Again, apologies for not being that concise with my question im new to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not saving because you never close the file. This is why most people agree `with open(filename, 'w+')` is best practice.

Try using the below format for `LoginScreen()`

```
def LoginScreen():
    print("Welcome to Area Trainer")
    print("Please enter the username for your account")
    global user_name
    user_name = str(input())
    with open(user_name + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(User_Points))

    # Remaining code below here...
```

I also noticed at the end of `MenuTriangle()` you try to add strings together rather than adding integers. You'll want to convert the string you read from file to an integer before increasing the score. You also don't provide which mode of opening the file you need. It does default to `'r'` but it's better to be explicit.

```
def MenuTriangle():

    # if: ...
    # elif: ...
    # elif: ...

    elif user_input == "B":
        print("Congratulations! You got it right, someone's a smart cookie. Here have two points!")

        with open(user_name + '.txt', 'r') as f:
            score = f.read()
            new_score = int(score) + 2
            print("Your score is {}".format(new_score))

        with open(user_name + '.txt', 'w+') as w:  # Wouldn't you want to overwrite this rather than continue appending numbers?
            w.write(str(new_score))

        MenuStart()  # Call this outside of your with statements so that the file closes
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I see what you have done now!  :D

Answer (score 1):

The addition that you are doing here

```
score = reading.read()
score = score + '2'
```

is of `type str` so you keep getting values like `024`, change the value in the file to `int` first.

```
    score = int(score) + '2'
```

Also open the file in `w+` mode

```
save = open(user_name + '.txt', 'w+')
```

or use `with` as it's been recommended by others.